# What is the purpose of non-mining sealer nodes in clique POA private ethereum network with respect to the clique consensus

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, consensus, poa, clique

I did setup a private POA ethereum network with 4 nodes with 3 of them mining . I went on to try a lot of combinations with some miners and sealers and reached to a conclusion that every miner hash to be a sealer otherwise it wont seal a block . However the network works fine with 3 sealers of them 2 mining and a non-mining sealer node.
My question is that how this non-mining sealer node is used in clique consensus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-mining sealer node which is also called non-validator nodes is just deployed so developers and users can connect with these nodes and can interact with the blockchain. As sealer nodes are critical so this is not opened to all. Few non-validators nodes are also good to run so that other non trusted users can connect to our network with limited access.